# Can I change the theme colors when I log in?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

Right now the list of questions on the entry page (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) has medium-blue text on a non-white background.  Also medium-gray text for the number of votes.

I know low-contrast sites are all the rage these days, but I find it hard to read text when there is not much contrast between the text and the background, especially when my screen is not at full brightness.

Is is possible to use a higher-contrast theme that is not too much work (manual editing of css files, for example).

Comment: So yes, manual editing of CSS, userscripts. No more variants.

Comment: We have no plans to support multiple themes per site right now, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The site's current look is sort of a default beta look and is temporary. To change it right now you'll have to use custom css stylesheets.

When(if) we launch, a professional will design a new look based on community feedback (assuming this hasn't changed in the last few years).

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exist as a built-in feature. But you can use alternate themes that other people have designed. [Search for theme](https://stackapps.com/search?q=theme) on [Stackapps](https://stackapps.com/). In particular, you may like [MinimalOverflow](https://stackapps.com/questions/2143/minimaloverflow-a-themescript-for-stack-exchange) (beware, it hasn't been updated in a while so it may be missing some elements), or [StackExchange Theme Switcher](https://stackapps.com/questions/2808/stackexchange-theme-switcher) if there's some other Stack Exchange site design that you really like.